# asp.net - how to get value from post method

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

In asp.net app i receive a form values from angular app.

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult addChange([FromBody] Change change)
        {
            return Json(change.Status);
        }
```

How to get object or some value of object to use it in another class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access property like that: change.PropertyName.
But you might send data from angular as FormData, then you should change [FromBody] to [FromForm].

It's most likely that you are doing something wrong at angular site. You should check this endpoint via postman.

Edit:
To use this object in another method you should pass it through.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult addChange([FromBody] Change change)
{
    AnotherMethod(change);
    return Json(change.Status);
}

public void AnotherMethod(Change change)
{
  var foo = change.Status;
}
```

Comment: change.property work only in that method addChange, but how can i do some in another method? Or i should  do all with that change only in this method?